# High CPU usage for UDP server

Tags: java, kotlin, server

I'm working on a simple UDP server. To receive packets I created a `Thread` subclass and in its `run()` method I have the following infinite loop:

```
val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Packet.MAX_PACKET_SIZE)

while (continueRunning) {
    buffer.clear()
    val address = socket.receive(buffer) // DatagramChannel in non-blocking mode
    buffer.flip()
 
    // No packets received, always null
    if (address != null) {
        val data = ByteArray(buffer.limit())
        buffer.get(data, 0, buffer.limit())
        val packet = DatagramPacket(data, data.size, address)

        // threadPool is created with Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
        threadPool.submit { packetProcessor.processPacket(packet) }
    }
 
    val answer = answerQueue.poll() // ConcurrentLinkedQueue

    // Answer queue is always empty, so this is always null as well
    if (answer != null) socket.send(ByteBuffer.wrap(answer.data), answer.socketAddress)
}
```

After calling `start()` function for this thread the application's CPU usage jumps to 15 - 25% and stays at this value while the thread is not stopped. I am actually okay with it. But I wonder if it is a normal situation when the server takes a lot of CPU time while doing nothing except of running an infinite loop? Or should I use some tricks to lower the CPU usage? And if I should, what should I do?

Comment: Continuous while loop (poller) without sleep can take 1 whole core of the CPU. Try adding 1ms sleep at the end of the while loop that should drastically reduce the CPU usage.

Comment: @SaifAhmad yeah, that's what I did in my client's app to reduce CPU and power usage. Although in the server app that will create a delay in 1 ms for receiving and sending packets. The whole millisecond seemed too much of a delay :) Especially when I expect to receive more than thousand packets per second. Anyway, I added sleep with a condition that there was no packets received and sent in a particular iteration and there is no active tasks in the thread pool, so I don't expect any work to do in the next iteration. Thanks for your comment :)